# Top 2 Rows from every same data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

This is interview question. 
If suppose I have one table & in that table only one column.

```
   Details

    a
    a
    a
    a
    b
    b
    b
    c
    d
    d
    d
```

This is the data. Now I want top 2 from every group like.

```
Details
a
a
b
b
c
d
d
```

How get this result.

Comment: Which way is the faster n better for performance to acheive this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Window Function` to get the top two rows in each group

```
SELECT Details
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()OVER(partition BY Details ORDER BY Details) rn
        FROM   tablename) a
WHERE  rn <= 2
```

**Note :** In `order by` change the order to `Asc` or `Desc` based on your requirement

Comment: Which way is the faster n better for performance to acheive this

Comment: As far i know this is the better way to get the result.